# JS - Do async functions parameter references get affected by synchronous code execution?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

**Do async functions parameter references get affected by synchronous code execution?**

To be more specific I am creating a little grid animation using an array of custom `<Tile/>`. Then in another function I am creating an array `animation` that holds "Keyframes" (I use the term loosely). Basically each index is an array of which `<Tile/>`s are changed in each "frame".

Then I have a `Render` function that takes that array of "keyframes" and renders them as follows:

```
// Returns a Promise that resolves after "ms" Milliseconds
const timer = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

//Renders gameboard tile by tile with given ms delay
async function render(animation) {
  
  for (var i = 0; i < animation.length; i++) {
    
    //do some rendering stuffs

    await timer(3000 / animation.length); // This *Should* ensure 3s of total animation time
  }
}
```

Now the question is if I were to add a "stopper" to this function in a way like:

```
//Renders gameboard tile by tile with given ms delay
async function render(animation, stop) {
  
  for (var i = 0; i < animation.length; i++) {
    if(stop){
       //stop rendering
    }
    //do some rendering stuffs

    await timer(3000 / animation.length); // This *Should* ensure 3s of total animation time
  }
}
```

Lets say I call `render` multiple times.

If I were to create a synchronous way to change the value of `stop` to true: Would it then pause the asynchronous stack of `render` calls, update stop, then resume the `render` calls only to then exit because of the conditional? OR am I just mistaken and would the `render` calls simply not run at all because SOME kind of synchronous code would have to be executing in order to change the value of `stop` synchronously and in the scope of the async calls to `render` stop would HAVE to be false in order for the synchronous code to be finished and the async stack to start.

Comment: "*If I were to create a synchronous way to change the value of `stop` to true*" - **how** would you do that? Notice that in multiple calls to `render`, you'd have multiple `stop` variables, each in its own scope.

Comment: if stop is a boolean no, the value is passed as a copy. if you pass an object however currentAnimation = {stop: false}; And change the value of stop during the animation, you will reach your stop condition

Comment: @Bergi  @user3252327 THAT was something I had wondered, if ```stop``` would be a reference to the value outside the ```render``` function or if it was "copied" per se and dealt with locally within the ```render``` function call

Comment: @NateBaker There's nothing special about `async` functions. [JavaScript is always pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/1048572). Does that answer your question or is there still an open question?

Comment: @Bergi This was kind of a two-part question: 1 - about exactly what you answered, and 2 - how to go about doing this a "better" way. which the latter was solved by code sprit. But nonetheless thank you!

Comment: The "better" way would be to pass an [`AbortSignal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortSignal) as a cancellation token to `render`, and to forward it to `timer`, so that you could `clearTimeout` when the signal is fired.

Comment: @Bergi Ooo I'll have to look into that, I'm unfamilliar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for is stopped after promise of previous item is resolved.

```
let stopped = false;

function isStopped() {
  return stopped;
}

function stop() {
  stopped = true;
}

function renderItems(items) {
  return items.reduce((promise, item) => {
    return promise.then(() => {
      // Checks if stopped after each promis resolves in order
      if (!isStopped()) {
      // Run next render callback
      return asyncRenderItem(item);
    } else {
      // Dont run next
      return;
    }
    });

  }, Promise.resolve());
}

async function asyncRenderItem(item) { ... }
```

Comment: "*note that your for loop wont wait for the await and will run all callbacks at once*" - no, of course it will wait! That's the whole point of `await` syntax.

Comment: Sry my mistake, ill edit it but the solution should work nonetheless.

Comment: Gotcha, so your thought is to, instead of trying to synchronously call ```render``` and change the value of ```stop``` you would just make the entire render process async and stop the headache. And this is why we go to stack overflow :D. I'll try it out and see how it works out, thank you! This was both a question of how references of variables are passed into the async stack as well as asking for guidance on a project.